# Is it code to have electrical wire going no where?

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I have a wall open in the center of my house.  I am going to run some 14-2 up it and and to about 5 feet from my panel, leaving plenty of extra wire to hook up in a few months.  On the other end I am going to just leave about 30 extra feet in the attic.  Is this code?

I will be installing pot lights on the main floor in 2-3 months and want to run this before I close up the wall this week.

Comment: Do you mean "is this permitted under code", or "is this a code violation?"

Comment: Either.  I will hide it from inspector though because don't feel like pulling a permit for 6 pot lights in a few months.

Comment: 14-3 in case you ever get inspired to add a remote switch?

Comment: @bib - I will go to a light switch first and 14-3 from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's legal.

<sup><sub>*Obligatory characters so the answer can be submitted*</sub></sup>

Comment: If it's Audio, Information Technology, Class 2, Class 3, PLTC, fire alarm, communication, coaxial, Network-powered Broadband,  optical fiber cable, or electrical circuits for pipe organs, it must be identified for future use with a tag.

Comment: Technically, since it's not connected to any electrical equipment or devices, I don't think it's even covered by NEC or any code for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest running a conduit instead. Something like 3/4" EMT. That will give you more flexibility in the future.

Comment: That sounds like extra work and money!

Comment: This sounds like a comment, not an answer.